# Django REST Framework - Azure AD from other Django App

Tags: authentication, django-rest-framework, azure-ad-msal

On one side, I am developing a Django Web App that uses Azure AD authentication following this tutorial [Enable user sign-in to your Django web app using Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/msid-django-web-app-sign-in/).
On the other side, I am developing a Django REST API on an existing Azure SQL server database to access it's data from other services such as the first mentioned Web App.
The two apps are on different Azure resources.

I am looking for a solution to only grant access to the API to users that are logged in the Web App using their Azure AD credentials but can't seem to find a solution to what I am looking for, except using Tokens but that does not seem to be the safest way. What would you recommend?